# Does this regular expression need PHP version 5.4+?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a shared hosting server that runs PHP version `5.3.28-nmm2`.
The following PHP code works for PHP 5.4 but doesn't work on my server:

```
$tweet = "hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö";
$res = preg_replace("/ #\p{L}+\b(?!\s+\p{L})/u", '', $tweet);
echo $res,"\n";
```

(it removes the hashtags from the end of the text)

There is no error, just no content in the `$res` echo. (completly empty)
Does the code need PHP 5.4+, if so, what part of it?

Comment: Is there any error log or error output occurred?

Comment: your original code seems to work fine look @ http://3v4l.org/XrRLq

Comment: @TruongHua No errors, just an empty echo.

Comment: @dbinns66 Do I understand right that the site uses PHP version `5.3.28-nmm2` and it works on their server? If so, what else could cause the problem on my server?

Comment: that site runs the code through many versions of PHP and displays the results and the versions of PHP that return a specific result, different results, different displays... very handy site, found it on SO in fact ;-)

Comment: Can you show me your phpinfo()

Comment: @TruongHua What info do you need from it?

Comment: @Tom Just check is your server support regex

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$res = preg_replace("/ #\w+/u", '', $tweet);


$tweet = "hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö";
$res = preg_replace("/ #\w+/u", '', $tweet);
echo $res,"\n";
```

RESULT PHP Version 5.3.29:

```
hello world foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme
```

Comment: Doesn't work either. Same problem as before - the output is empty and no error message. Any ideas?